# how to send a message from one windows console application to another?

Tags: c++, winapi, ipc, windows-messages

I have a windows console application which starts child process.
How can I send a message to child process?
I found functions like [PostMessage()/PeekMessage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - that's what I need, but as I understand, it is used inside one application, and uses HWND to identify the target window (I have no windows in application).
Also I've read materials about [ipc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), for example named pipes demand HWND too.
I want something like that:

```
[program 1]

int main()
{
    CreateProcess(.., processInfo);
    SendMessage(processId, message);
}

[program 2]

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
//      do thw work
        Sleep(5 * 1000);
//      check message
        if(PeekMessage(message,..))
        {
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Child process needs to get message that it should finish its work, not terminate immediately, but finish current iteration. That's why I don't use signals and blocking 'receive message' is not appropriate too.

Comment: Already found PostThreadMessage(), it helped! Thank you ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
[program 1]
int main()
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    std::string path = "c:\\program2.exe";
    CreateProcess(path.c_str(), .. , &si, &pi ) ) 
    Sleep(12 * 1000); // let program2 do some work
    PostThreadMessage(pi.dwThreadId, 100, 0, 0);
}

[program 2]
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    MSG message;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "working" << std::endl;
        Sleep(2 * 1000);
        if(PeekMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a [Message-Only Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#message_only).

This is a window which is only used for sending and receiving messages. You can create it by specifying `HWND_MESSAGE` as the window parent.

Answer (score 0):

In program 1 you should use the FindWindow function to get handle of program 2

and then use SendMessage function

[program 1]

```
    int main()
    {
     HWND hwnd=FindWindow(NULL,formText);//formText name of program 2
        if(hwnd!=0)
        {
            COPYDATASTRUCT cd;
        cd.dwData = 100;
        cd.cbData = 100;
        cd.lpData = msg;                //msg additional data
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_COPYDATA, 0, (LPARAM)(&cd));
        }
    }

[program 2]

    void handlemessage(MSG *msg)
    {
        //handle
    }


    int main()
   {

        MSG msg;
        while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
        {
           handlemessage(&msg);
        }
    }
```