# Mandatory treatments on PC shutdown in C++

Tags: c++, windows, shutdown

I'd like to create an application which alerts another one when the computer is shutting down.

Is the function

```
onShutdown() {
    [Send my message]
}
```

a guanrantee that my alert will go from one application to another when the PC is shutting down ?

EDIT : Reading the comments, I'll add that it seems mandatory to be the first one to get the termination messages. Is there a way to get that message since the "onShutdown()" may be not sufficient to guarantee that my application will be the first to be stopped ?

RE-EDIT : For IHM, it seems best to use

```
WindowProc() {}
```

And for non-IHM, it seems best to use :

```
SetConsoleCtrlHandler();
```

Still got no clue for a non-window application.

Comment: Have you read this article? [Message-only Windows on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#message_only) Also possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20029338/how-to-send...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20029338/how-to-send-a-message-from-one-windows-console-application-to-another)

Comment: That would not be reliable. What if the other application received the `WM_ENDSESSION` message first and has already terminated?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Would there be a way to have his application be the first one to receive the message somehow? Or do applications receive the message at random order?

Comment: @John, to my knowledge, the order is arbitrary.

Comment: It's probably sent in parallel to all top-level windows.  Apps then shut down concurrently.

Comment: There's no reason to be voting to close this: the question is clear, specific, and represents an attempt by the poster to solve their problem.

Comment: Windows sends a warning to every top-level window of every application already (WM_QUERYENDSESSION).  Why can't the program rely on this instead of on another program relaying the warning?  Also, `onShutdown` doesn't tell us much.  When is `onShutdown` called?

Answer (score 1):

You can send the message in responce to `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`. Now it's possible for the other application to go away literally at any moment, so there is no 100% guarantee possible anyway. However, `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` is quite unlikely to trigger an application shutdown, so there's no specific reason to fear the other application will die at just that moment.

Comment: You can also block before returning from `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` (I think up to 5 seconds is allowed, before Windows pops up accusing messages), to give the other app time to handle the message.

Comment: Okay, but is the function "LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc() {}" applicable for a process which doesn't have a Man-To-Machine Interface ?

Comment: @Xaltar: See first comment, from John Odom

Comment: This works only for an application that has a window. What about a process-only application ?

Comment: Well, I did. The WM_QUERYENDSESSION is received through the WindowProc() function. This needs a Handler to a window. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. What should I put for the window Handler ? I don't have a window ... Sorry I'm a bit lost here ...

Comment: @Xaltar: John Odom/MSDN told you how to create a window.

Comment: Well, I want to avoid using windows ... so, with only a process but no windows, is this function useable ?

Comment: Yes. Just create a hidden window.